# income tax liability

Tags: taxes, india, income, gift-tax

My son is working in Nederland. He first transferred money to his saving account in India and from there he transferred the money to my saving account (about RS 7 lakh), I need to know whether this money is taxable to me and/or should be added to my income?

Answer (score 1):

Your son can gift you unlimited amount of money. It does not fall under income tax. It falls under gift tax. As per gift tax there is no tax for you. Any interest you earn on this is taxable to you.

Your son transferred into savings account... if your son is NRI he can't hold savings account. Ask him to open a NRE account and convert savings account to NRO account.